# Output shape of tf.nn.conv2d_transpose is entirely undefined even though only batch size unknown

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the following code to compute a 2D deconvolution in Tensorflow:

```
def deconv2d_strided(input_, filter_h, filter_w, channels_in, channels_out, output_shape,
                     pool_factor=2, name='deconv', reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=reuse):
        w = tf.get_variable(...)
        b = tf.get_variable(...)
        minus_b = tf.subtract(input_, b)

        # dynamic shape of input_:
        in_shape = tf.shape(input_)
        out_shape = [in_shape[0], output_shape[0].value, output_shape[1].value, channels_out]
        out = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(minus_b,
                                     filter=w,
                                     output_shape=tf.pack(out_shape),
                                     strides=[1, pool_factor, pool_factor, 1],
                                     padding='SAME')
        return out
```

The problem I'm facing is that the shape of `out` looks like `shape=(?, ?, ?, ?)` even though the `out_shape` I pass into the function is fully defined except for the first dimension (which is the batch size). I.e.

```
out_shape = <class 'list'>: [<tf.Tensor 'decoder/conv_l4/strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, 5, 15, 256]
```

How can I get the shape of `out` to look like `(?, 5, 15, 256)`?

I want the shape to be defined as fully as possible, because the output of this is going into a batch normalization layer, and for this to work, the channels dimension (which is the last) must be fully defined otherwise Tensorflow complains (cf. [`tf.contrib.layers.python.layers.batch_norm`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py)). So, if you have a solution how I can pass a tensor with undefined channel dimension into the batch normalization layer, that would also work for me, though I would prefer to get this thing right and figure out why the output shape of `conv2d_transpose` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic has already been discussed in TensorFlow Issues, and it seems that they still have to fix it.

Here you have the [Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/833#), and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/833#issuecomment-278016198) can solve your problem.

Comment: Another possible workaround I got from [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8972) is to use `out.set_shape([None] + out_shape[1:])`